# Pandas dataframe split by group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe consisting of various groups, e.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 2], ['A', 3], ['A', 6], ['B',8], ['B', 2], ['B', 3], ['C', 6], ['C', 2], ['C', 3], ['C', 6]], columns=['Group', 'Val'])

df['count'] = df.groupby('Group')['Group'].transform('count') #get counts per group
```

```
    Group   Val count
0   A      2    3
1   A      3    3
2   A      6    3
3   B      8    3
4   B      2    3
5   B      3    3
6   C      6    4
7   C      2    4
8   C      3    4
9   C      6    4
```

I would like to split the dataframe into `df_train` and `df_test` where `df_train` contains the first (by index) ROUNDUP(0.6*count) rows for that group whereas the remainder, the last count-ROUNDUP(0.6*count) rows, will go into the `df_test`. i.e., in my example it would take the first ROUNDUP(0.6*3)=2 rows for groups A and B and the first ROUNDUP(0.6*4)=3 rows for group C and put them in `df_train`, and the other rows--here the last row of each group--in `df_test`.

What's the best way to do in this in pandas?

**Additional notes**:

It may help to know that in my actual use-case I've sorted the data-frame by Date (within Group) so that the 'last' rows of each Group are actually the latest by Date. So we could select, within group, the appropriate number of rows by Date as well if that way works...

Answer (score 1):

Grouped by 'Goup' and 'count', each count is multiplied by a constant and specified as an integer in `head()`.
Note: As math.ceil() can't be applied to Pandas.Series, we're adding the constants again to make them round up. This logic doesn't always produce the result you're looking for. Please verify.

```
rows = 0.6
gb = df.groupby(['Group','count'])
# Since a rounding-up function cannot be applied to a series
df_train = gb.head(((df['count']*rows)+rows).round().astype(int))
df_train

Group   Val count
0   A   2   3
1   A   3   3
3   B   8   3
4   B   2   3
6   C   6   4
7   C   2   4
8   C   3   4
df_test = df[~(df.index.isin(df_train.index))]
df_test
Group   Val count
2   A   6   3
5   B   3   3
9   C   6   4
```